# I keep getting a TypeError and want the program to average a list

Tags: python

I keep getting the error - TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

```
temp = []
temp1 = input(int())
temp.append(temp1)

average = sum(temp)/len(temp)
print(average)
```

I have excluded most of the input code as it is long and not optimized.

Comment: Try `temp1 = int(input())` instead.

Comment: @j1-lee Thank you so much I don't know how such a simple mistake gave me such heartache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it might be `int(input())` not `input(int())` instead. :D

because int() is 0, but input() argument is a string not int, so that the error occurs

Answer (score 1):

`input()` returns a type of `str` and this is probably where your issue is coming from. Instead convert to `int` *after* taking input such as

```
temp1 = int(input())
```